# How to load a huggingface pretrained transformer model directly to GPU?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I want to load a huggingface pretrained transformer model directly to GPU (not enough CPU space)
e.g. loading BERT

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

would be loaded to CPU until executing

```
model.to('cuda')
```

now the model is loaded into GPU

I want to load the model directly into GPU when executing `from_pretrained`. Is this possible?

Comment: In the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.0.2/model_doc/auto.html#transformers.AutoConfig) you can see that there is no parameter that allows you to load a model on GPU using `from_pretrained`.

Comment: thanks! I thought there might be a way to indirectly do this by setting some parameter before loading the model or something like this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm answering my own question

huggingface accelerate could be helpful in moving the model to GPU before it's fully loaded in CPU, so it worked when
GPU memory > model size > CPU memory
by using `device_map = 'cuda'`

```
!pip install accelerate
```

then use

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", device_map = 'cuda')
```